# Change Taxonomist's definition

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, taxonomist-badge

How 'bout we change the definition of the Taxonomist badge from *"Created a tag used by 50 questions"* to *"Created a tag used by 50 **users**"*? That would prevent users from trying to game the badge by editing 50 questions just to add a new junk tag.

Promoted from my answer here:
[Stop stupid tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14595/stop-stupid-tags/14646#14646)

Comment: Jeff has previously declared this a suplex-able offense. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4760/does-it-matter-that-people-game-badges/4762#4762  :)

Answer (score 9):

Verily, my campaign for my Taxonomist badge for [waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles) shall end.

Nonetheless, I support this. It's a great way to kill potential gaming with that badge.

Comment: Must remember to waffle on a question.

Answer (score 4):

This would remove some of the incentive to create better tags and add them to appropriate questions, usually done by people knowledgeable in the field.  Badges are there to create incentive to do the best things for the site.

Answer (score 2):

Rules to change the badge were suggested before, but denied by Jeff because he did not see any cases where the badge was exploited. Even with my own "*research*", I could't find any cases where it was obviously exploited. I know it seems kind of backwards when **everyone** *assumes* the worst -- but no one actually does it, so really we just end up making this a much bigger issue than it really is.

Comment: It would be a lot of work for a fairly intangible reward

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be something like:

> Created a tag that is used on at least
>   50 question counting no more than 5
>   usages by each user.

We could still have people creating accounts to game the system, but it would then be a clear case of gaming.

Comment: Weird, I was just writing a very similar answer.  My criteria was slightly different though; *'Created a tag that was used on 50 questions by at least 20 users'*. Yours is pretty much the same (except it's *'at least 10 users'*).

Comment: @Andy, we both aiming for "the tag has proved it is useful..."

Comment: The "user" should be the person that did the tagging, or the person that asked the question