# Is this type of gaming the system for badges allowed?

Tags: discussion, badges, gaming-the-system

https://stackexchange.com/users/237100/kevin?tab=accounts

This user, exists on every single SE network. Makes no contributions, no rep, no badges except for 2.

A silver one for 30 days activity, and a gold one for 100 days activity. On every single site.

The one site he does have rep on is for answering a question on Server Fault. The topic of the question he answered i hear you ask? **Scheduling automated jobs**.

This could be a huge coincidence, but i highly doubt a user has been logging in every day for 100 days on every single SE site without making a single other contribution.

All activity badges are awarded on the same days too.

**Is this sort of behavior allowed?** It's doing no harm but i imagine that there would be a very quick resolution if a user was discovered to be gaming the system for any other badges.

Comment: notice Kevin's alleged age? 92!

Comment: There is a bug report somewhere with a specific browser plugin you get SO activity on every day you start/use the browser.

Comment: Note that he used to have an answer on Programmers that got deleted - note the Teacher and Supporter badges he has there

Comment: Maybe he just loves gold badges and this was the easiest way to get 100+ gold badges "quickly".

Comment: THE PRICE OF GOLD IS GOING TO GO SKY-HIGH! HE MUST BE STOPPED

Comment: @Doorknob Programmers seems to be his main one, as its one of 2 where he has bothered to vote. the rest are just automated

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill - Surely with over-supply the price would dive?

Comment: So, the OP has loads of badges on their combined flair. Woohoo. What's the harm? It's not like they can _do_ anything with them.

Comment: @Oded Actually you need 200 rep for a site to show up on combined flair, so not even that :P

Comment: @Oded i accept there is no immediate harm, it just seems off, my question is my last line. Is this sort of behavior allowed? If someone gamed any other badge i imagine there would be a very quick resolution

Comment: A 92-year old man who likes to collect gold badges. Gentlemen, I think we've just stumbled onto a threat to the very existence of SE platform.

Comment: If he has done all these to get the badges, well, he *is* a fanatic.

Comment: Dear SE, why do you limit the age of registrants to 92? What have you got against most nonagenarians, let alone the super-centenarians?

Comment: @Doorknob - true enough. And not a single site with +60 in sight. So... ?

Comment: @Oded -- I imagined he was hoarding/cornering the market, which would drive the price up. </pedant>

Comment: It may be indicative of an account primarily used for harvesting data from the sites. Can a moderator somehow access the browsing history across the sites?

Comment: @juergend this plugin is called start page ^^

Comment: @DuncanJones: it's all CC-wiki and available without logging in anyway. I don't see why that would be a problem.

Comment: Stumbled across this related old post just now: [Does it matter that people “Game” Badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4760/does-it-matter-that-people-game-badges)

Answer (score 16):

I face similar temptation every day...

[image]

In these hard times, we have to do what we can to stay afloat.

Comment: I find staring at 'em shiny badges to be therapeutic.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe he is using scripts, or maybe he is just an eager reader and reads SE sites every day by breakfast?

What's the difference, anyway? What's the worth of badges earned for visited a site every 100 consecutive days? It's only a sign you haven't gone out even for one weekend in that time. They are achieved for logging every day. Is the manual logging by breakfast gaining the system?

There are probably more people feeling pity for you for having those badges than envying you. The potential damage from such gaming is practically none.

Unicorns don't die because someone has won a badge. Especially such slight-weight as those pure-clicking ones.

Comment: A unicorn is *born* each time someone wins a badge. And downvotes a question.

Answer (score 0):

You only get Fanatic and Enthusiast once

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: You can only get them once per site. He has them on 36-37 different sites.